# Why does awk do nothing here?

Tags: awk, zsh, gawk

```
echo "$(time perlscript > /dev/null)" | mawk '{ print $9 }'
```

returns the entire output of echo, not the ninth column as I hoped. Why?

Comment: It seems likely that perlscript is writing its output to stderr, and that is what you are seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do something with `time` result you have to wrap it within a subshell and redirect stderr to stdout as follows:

```
$ (time sleep 0) 2>&1 | awk '{print $2}'

0m0.006s
0m0.000s
0m0.000s
```

Because something like this seems to be *ignoring* me:

```
$ time sleep 0 | grep real

real    0m0.011s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.008s
```

and so does this:

```
$ time sleep 0 2>&1 | grep real

real    0m0.012s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.004s
```